# Expectation of $h \circ X$

Tags: expected-value, density-function, continuous-data, integral

I'm only starting to learn statistics.

The definition I've been given for the expected value (expectation) of a continuous random variable X with probability density function (PDF) $f_X$ is the following

$$
E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x)xdx
$$

Despite only beginning stats, I've already stumbled many times on the use of a property that was not explicited and that I don't find any explanation for. I don't know the exact conditions of application of this property, but it seems that $E[h(X)]$, where h is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, that, I guess, has to verify some conditions, is often expressed, by some people as:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(x)f_X(x)dx
$$

For example, in the course I'm following, they define the variance $Var(X)$ as the expectation of $(X - \mu)^2$. All I get from this definition is that if $f_{(X-\mu)^2}$ is the PDF of $(X - \mu)^2$, then

$$
Var(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{(X-\mu)^2}(x)xdx
$$

Yet, without other explanation, the variance is replaced with the following expression:

$$
Var(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x-\mu)^2f_X(x)dx
$$

during the course.
Other example, in this post:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133474/67507

it is written that ($f$ being the PDF of $X$):
$$
E[X^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^2 f(x) dx}
$$

Integration is also a work in progress for me at the moment, so probably I'm just missing some basic property of integrals to make this step from
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{h \circ X}(x)xdx
$$
to
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(x)f_X(x)dx
$$
But what is the theorem/property that allows to do that and where can I find a proof of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This property is sometimes called the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician); Wikipedia has [some proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Proof) in different settings. You're right that it is not immediately obvious from the original definition.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!